# How to fix an error "Actions must be plain objects"?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, action, redux-saga

I am new to working with sagas, I can’t solve the problem of "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

I enclose all the necessary code. Already broke his head, solving the issue.
I hope for your help.

I looked at the documentation of the sagas, but did not find anything about this error.
I also watched the react boilerplate, where there are already sagas, but I would like to do this on CRA

action

```
import { AXIOS } from "../api";

import { takeLatest, put, call } from "redux-saga/effects";

export const GET_GENRES_PENDING = "GENRES::GET_GENRES_PENDING";
export const GET_GENRES_FULFILLED = "GENRES::GET_GENRES_FULFILLED";
export const GET_GENRES_REJECTED = "GENRES::GET_GENRES_REJECTED";

export const getGenresPending = () => ({
  type: GET_GENRES_PENDING
});

export const getGenresFulfilled = data => ({
  type: GET_GENRES_FULFILLED,
  payload: data
});

export const getGenresRejected = error => ({
  type: GET_GENRES_REJECTED,
  payload: error
});

export function* getGenresAction() {
  try {
    yield put(getGenresPending());
    const data = yield call(() => {
      return AXIOS.get(
        "/movie/list?api_key=5fcdb863130c33d2cb8f1612b76cbd30&language=ru-RU"
      ).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    });
    yield put(getGenresFulfilled(data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getGenresRejected(error));
  }
}

export default function* watchFetchGenres() {
  yield takeLatest("FETCHED_GENRES", getGenresAction);
}
```

store

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import watchFetchGenres from "./actions/getGenresAction";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export function configureStore(initialState) {
  const middleware = [sagaMiddleware];
  const composeEnhancers =
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  );
  sagaMiddleware.run(watchFetchGenres);
  return store;
}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import App from "./containers/App";

import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

import { configureStore } from "./core/configureStore.js";

const store = configureStore({});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import MoviesContainer from "./MoviesContainer/MoviesContainer";
import FilterContainer from "./FilterContainer/FilterContainer";

import { Container, GlobalStyle } from "./style.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container className="app">
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={FilterContainer} />
        <Route path="/movies" component={MoviesContainer} />
      </Router>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Container

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

import watchFetchGenres from "../../core/actions/getGenresAction";

import Card from "../../components/Card/Card";
import Button from "../../components/Button/Button";
import TextInput from "../../components/TextInput/TextInput";
import { TitleH1, TitleH2, TitleCard } from "../../components/Title/Title";

import { Container, SecondaryContainer } from "../style.js";

class FilterContainer extends React.Component {
  // const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   getGenresAction();
  //   // fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=5fcdb863130c33d2cb8f1612b76cbd30&language=en-US')
  // });

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.watchFetchGenres();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <TitleH1 title="Фильтры" />
        <SecondaryContainer>
          <TextInput placeholder="Введите название фильма" />
        </SecondaryContainer>
        <SecondaryContainer filters>
          <Card>
            <TitleCard title="Фильтр по жанру" />
          </Card>
          <Card>
            <TitleCard title="Фильтр по рейтингу" />
          </Card>
          <Card>
            <TitleCard title="Фильтр по году" />
          </Card>
        </SecondaryContainer>
        <SecondaryContainer>
          <Button primary value="Применить фильтры" placeholder="lala" />
        </SecondaryContainer>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  genres: state.genres
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ watchFetchGenres }, dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FilterContainer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> bindActionCreators({ watchFetchGenres }, dispatch);

watchFetchGenres isn't an action creator, so this isn't correct. An action creator is function which returns an action. You have 3 examples of them in your code:

```
export const getGenresPending = () => ({
  type: GET_GENRES_PENDING
});

export const getGenresFulfilled = data => ({
  type: GET_GENRES_FULFILLED,
  payload: data
});

export const getGenresRejected = error => ({
  type: GET_GENRES_REJECTED,
  payload: error
});
```

Those are the types of things you should be binding instead.

Your saga is listening for actions of type "FETCHED_GENRES", so the 3 existing action creators won't work for that. You may need to create another action creator, as in:

```
export const fetchGenres = () => ({
  type: 'FETCHED_GENRES',
});
```

Then in your mapDispatchToProps, you'll make use of this action creator:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ fetchGenres }, dispatch);
```

And update where you call it:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchGenres();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ten minutes ago, I understood what the error was, created additional action and everything worked out.